# Unix substring file name by 3rd symbol - "_" from right side

Tags: shell, unix

i have a list of files like :

```
File_one_1_11_1
File_two_v1_22_1
File_three_2_31_5
```

My questions is how to substring file name to have a list like this:

```
File_one
File_two
File_three
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a file containing those lines, is this a shell variable, are these filenames in a directory, or something written down in some paper?

Answer (score 3):

```
 echo "File_one_1_11_1" | rev | cut -d"_" -f4-  | rev
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done easily by `sed`'s back reference capability, try following, written and tested with shown samples(by OP's posted answer could see these are the values which OP reading from either a variable OR from an Input_file).

```
sed 's/\([^_]*\)\(_[^_]*\)_.*/\1\2/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation will be, using `sed`'s substitution capability to substitute everything with 1st and 2nd captured groups(which is done in regex part before substitution part).

OR with simple `awk` it will be just:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {print $1,$2}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have one of those filenames stored in a variable `filename`, i.e.

```
filename=File_one_1_11_1
```

you can do a

```
residual_name=${filename%_*_*_*}
```